# matching and joining key/val of dictionaries in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

this is a list, I got lists like this :

```
k = [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}, {d:4}, {a: 5}] and t = [{a:6}, {b:7}, {c:8}, {d:9}, {a: 10}]
```

if `a`'s dictionary key in `k` is matching with `t`'s dictionary key in `t`, then extract value and key in dictionary
and then I want to reorganize like below:

```
newlist = [a is 1 and 6, b is 2 and 7, c is 3 and 8, d is 4 and 9, a is 5 and 10]
```

Comment: hint: read about `defaultdict`.

Comment: why don't you let us know what you tried and why it did or didn't work?

Comment: There are two dictionaries in both lists which have an `a` entry. Also, the syntax of your lists is only valid if you have existing variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` - otherwuse the correct syntax is e.g. `{‘a’:1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it is little hard to understand what you require exactly, but I have done my best to obtain what I think you need! :-)

```
k = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}, {'d':4}, {'a': 5}]
t = [{'a':6}, {'b':7}, {'c':8}, {'d':9}, {'a': 10}]
newlist = []

for i in range(min(len(k), len(t))):
    letter_k, value_k = [*k[i].items()][0]
    letter_t, value_t = [*t[i].items()][0]
    if letter_k == letter_t:
        newlist.append({letter_k: [value_k, value_t]})
```

This will yield:

```
newlist = [{'a': [1, 6]}, {'b': [2, 7]}, {'c': [3, 8]}, {'d': [4, 9]}, {'a': [5, 10]}]
```

Note that I did not combine the dictionaries due to duplicate keys!

Comment: @nayang - Thanks for your feedback! It would be great if you could upvote this solution - if you haven't already :-)